# iPhone tries to load local open WiFi login page over mobile data

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

When connecting to my college's open WiFi network my iPhone attempts to open the pop-up login page over it's mobile data.

The issue is that this page is obviously only available over the internal WiFi, and thus the page cannot be displayed.

To fix this, I disabled the mobile data, connected to the open WiFi, logged in, and then re-enabled the mobile data.

I was wondering if anyone had any tips to make this a bit easier?

Thanks

Comment: Does your college's network have a way to permanently associate your device with the network?  I understand this is the way you *have* been connecting, but is there a way to register your device with the network?

Comment: It's less an issue of association with the network I think - if the connection on the client end isn't used for around 10 minutes, you get 'booted' and have to login again (for security).

Comment: I was referring to permanent association which does not require you to constantly log in. I just wanted to check to see if there were other avenues.  Can you not connect to the open wifi directly under wifi even with mobile data enabled? This sounds like there's just a hiccup in the getting temporary connection lease you need to get full access.

Comment: What you mentioned you did in your question is the easiest way to go about what you're asking.